# Sleep until a specific time/date

Tags: bash, sleep, wait

I want my bash script to sleep until a specific time. So, I want a command like "sleep" which takes no interval but an end time and sleeps until then.

The "at"-daemon is not a solution, as I need to block a running script until a certain date/time.

Is there such a command?

Comment: Note that solution that simply uses a long sleep preceded by a calculation may sleep too long, maybe much too long especially if you have a machine that can go hibernate.  The posix sleep command makes no promises about not sleeping too long.  The solution by @Camusensei addresses the concern very nicely.

Comment: @GregD Please have a look at my [Jan 2023: New chapter about GregD's comment and hibernation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19067658/1765658)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

As mentioned by Outlaw Programmer, I think the solution is just to sleep for the correct number of seconds.

To do this in bash, do the following:

```
current_epoch=$(date +%s)
target_epoch=$(date -d '01/01/2010 12:00' +%s)

sleep_seconds=$(( $target_epoch - $current_epoch ))

sleep $sleep_seconds
```

To add precision down to nanoseconds (effectively more around milliseconds) use e.g. this syntax:

```
current_epoch=$(date +%s.%N)
target_epoch=$(date -d "20:25:00.12345" +%s.%N)

sleep_seconds=$(echo "$target_epoch - $current_epoch"|bc)

sleep $sleep_seconds
```

Note that macOS / OS X does not support precision below seconds, you would need to use `coreutils` from `brew` instead →  [see these instructions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/135742/14994)

Comment: Thanks for that, I wrote a small shell-script to get a "sleepuntil" command.

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist: There is a similar command call "at", that runs async.

Comment: If you want to stop tomorrow at 3 AM, you can use `target_epoch=$(date -d 'tomorrow 03:00' +%s)` instead.

Comment: You could do same by using one fork to `date` instead of two! See 1st part of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19067658/1765658)

Comment: Just discovered that `time` accepts floats on my Linux !

Comment: Avoid **multiple** forks when trying to work around ***nanoseconds***! Use `date -f - +%s.%N` in a [long running background process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49195703/1765658) (look for ***Quick demo***).

Comment: Note that this solution can potentially sleep too long, and if your machine hibernates a bit, it can be much too long.

Comment: Note, that `sleep` has a flaw - it sleeps for actual machine time. In other words, it ignores your computer sleeping (sorry for the pun). If you `sleep` for 2min, while putting the machine into sleep (or hibernate) for 1min, then in "human" time your script will sleep for 3min. To be precise, the question is "Sleep _until_ a specific date/time", not "Sleep _for_ a specific time", so all answers with basic `sleep` are not fully correct

Answer (score 57):

**Sample edited: Wed Apr 22 2020, something between 10:30 and 10h:55**
 (Important for reading samples)

## General method (Avoid useless forks!)

As this question was asked 4 years ago, this first part concerns *old* bash versions:

(Nota: this method use `date -f` wich is no POSIX and don't work under MacOS! If under Mac, goto my *pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) function*)

In order to reduce `forks`, instead of running `date` two times, I prefer to use this:

### Simple starting sample

```bash
sleep $(( $(date -f - +%s- <<< "tomorrow 21:30"$'\nnow') 0 ))
```

where `tomorrow 21:30` could be replaced by any kind of date and format recognized by `date`, in the future .

```bash
if read -rp "Sleep until: "  targetTime ;then
    sleep $(( $(date -f - +%s- <<< "$targetTime"$'\nnow') 0 ))
fi
```

### With high precision (nanosec)

Nearly same:

```bash
sleep $(bc <<<s$(date -f - +'t=%s.%N;' <<<$'07:00 tomorrow\nnow')'st-t')
```

### Reaching **next time**

For reaching *next `HH:MM`* meaning today if possible, tomorrow if too late:

```bash
sleep $((($(date -f - +%s- <<<21:30$' tomorrow\nnow')0)%86400))
```

This works under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) and other modern shells, but you have to use:

```bash
sleep $(( ( $(printf 'tomorrow %s\nnow\n' 21:30 | date -f - +%s-)0 )%86400 ))
```

under *lighter* shells like [busybox](/questions/tagged/busybox), [ash](/questions/tagged/ash) or [dash](/questions/tagged/dash) (one pipe/fork more).

## *Pure* [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) way, no fork!!

Tested under MacOS!

I wrote <s>one</s> two little functions: `sleepUntil` and `sleepUntilHires`

```
 Syntax:
 sleepUntil [-q] <HH[:MM[:SS]]> [more days]
     -q Quiet: don't print sleep computed argument
     HH          Hours (minimal required argument)
     MM          Minutes (00 if not set)
     SS          Seconds (00 if not set)
     more days   multiplied by 86400 (0 by default)
```

As new versions of bash do offer a `printf` option to retrieve date, for this new way to ***sleep until HH:MM*** whithout using `date` or any other fork, I've build a little [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) function. Here it is:

```bash
sleepUntil() { # args: [-q] <HH[:MM[:SS]]> [more days]
    local slp tzoff now quiet=false
    [ "$1" = "-q" ] && shift && quiet=true
    local -a hms=(${1//:/ })
    printf -v now '%(%s)T' -1
    printf -v tzoff '%(%z)T' $now
    tzoff=$((0${tzoff:0:1}(3600*10#${tzoff:1:2}+60*10#${tzoff: -2})))
    slp=$(((( 86400 + ( now - now%86400 ) +
                10#$hms*3600+10#${hms[1]:-0}*60+10#${hms[2]:-0} -
                tzoff - now
            ) % 86400 ) + 10#${2:-0} * 86400
          ))
    $quiet || printf 'sleep %ss, -> %(%c)T\n' $slp $((now+slp))
    read -t $slp _
}
```

Then:

```
sleepUntil 10:37 ; date +"Now, it is: %T"
sleep 49s, -> Wed Apr 22 10:37:00 2020
Now, it is: 10:37:00

sleepUntil -q 10:37:44 ; date +"Now, it is: %T"
Now, it is: 10:37:44

sleepUntil 10:50 1 ; date +"Now, it is: %T"
sleep 86675s, -> Thu Apr 23 10:50:00 2020
^C
```

If target is *before* this will sleep until tomorrow:

```
sleepUntil 10:30 ; date +"Now, it is: %T"
sleep 85417s, -> Thu Apr 23 10:30:00 2020
^C

sleepUntil 10:30 1 ; date +"Now, it is: %T"
sleep 171825s, -> Fri Apr 24 10:30:00 2020
^C
```

## HiRes time with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) under GNU/Linux

Recent [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), from version 5.0 add new `$EPOCHREALTIME` variable with microseconds. From this there is a `sleepUntilHires` function.

```bash
sleepUntilHires() { # args: [-q] <HH[:MM[:SS[.xxx]]]> [more days]
    local slp tzoff now quiet=false musec musleep tmu
    [ "$1" = "-q" ] && shift && quiet=true
    local -a hms
    IFS=: read -a hms <<<${1}
    printf -v tmu %.06f ${hms[2]:-0}
    printf -v hms[2] %.0f ${tmu%.*}
    tmu=${tmu#*.}
    printf -v now '%(%s)T' -1
    IFS=. read now musec <<<$EPOCHREALTIME
    musleep=$((2000000+10#$tmu-10#$musec))
    printf -v tzoff '%(%z)T\n' $now
    tzoff=$((0${tzoff:0:1}(3600*10#${tzoff:1:2}+60*10#${tzoff:3:2})))
    slp=$(((( 86400 + ( now - now%86400 ) +
                10#$hms*3600+10#0${hms[1]:-0}*60+10#${hms[2]:-0} -
                tzoff - now - 1
            ) % 86400 ) + 10#${2:-0} * 86400
          )).${musleep:1}
    $quiet ||
        printf 'sleep %ss, -> %(%c)T.%s\n' $slp $((now+${slp%.*}+1)) $tmu
    read -t $slp _
}
```

Please note: this use `read -t` wich is built-in, instead of `sleep`. Unfortunely, this won't work when running in background, without real TTY. Feel free to replace `read -t` by `sleep` if you
plan to run this in background scripts... (But for background process, consider using `cron` and/or `at` instead of all this)

### HiRes sleep until next *period*

About [RonJohn's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645992/sleep-until-a-specific-time-date/19067658#comment133547834_19067658), if the goal is to start every 15 minutes, `sleep` command could become:

```
sleepUntilNext() { # args: [-q] <float period in seconds>
    local slp sec mus quiet=0 res=0 chr
    [[ $1 == -q ]] && quiet=1 && shift
    printf -v slp %.6f $1
    slp=00000$(( 10#${slp/.} - ${EPOCHREALTIME/.} % 10#${slp/.} ))
    printf -v slp %.6f ${slp::-6}.${slp: -6}
    ((quiet)) || printf 'Sleep %s...' $slp >&2
    IFS= read -d '' -rsn1 -t $slp chr &&
        printf -v res %d \'"$chr"
    IFS=. read sec mus <<<$EPOCHREALTIME
    ((quiet)) || {
        IFS=. read sec mus <<<$EPOCHREALTIME
        printf '\rDone: %(%a %d %T)T.%s\e[K\n' $sec $mus >&2
    }
    return $res
}
```

Then for a period of 15':

```
sleepUntilNext 900
Sleep 662.334231...
Done: Wed 26 16:15:00.000171
```

for 20':

```
sleepUntilNext 1200
Sleep 11.509587...
Done: Wed 26 16:20:00.000168
```

But this accept *float* values as period:

```
while sleepUntilNext -q 1.5;do date +%T.%N;done
16:32:49.502416682
16:32:51.001073971
16:32:52.502804292
16:32:54.002940518
16:32:55.503174242
```

(Replace `read -t` by `sleep` or use pseudo FD... see ***About sleep and/or read -t*** further)

Skip next paragraph for tests and warning about `$ËPOCHSECONDS`!

#### Older method using `/proc/timer_list`, avoided to normal user, by recent Kernel!!

Under Linux kernel, you will find a variables file named `/proc/timer_list` where you could read an `offset` and a `now` variable, in **nanoseconds**. So we may compute sleep time to reach the *very top* desired time.

(I wrote this to generate and track specific events on very big log files, containing thousand line for one second).

```bash
mapfile  </proc/timer_list _timer_list
for ((_i=0;_i<${#_timer_list[@]};_i++));do
    [[ ${_timer_list[_i]} =~ ^now ]] && TIMER_LIST_SKIP=$_i
    [[ ${_timer_list[_i]} =~ offset:.*[1-9] ]] && \
    TIMER_LIST_OFFSET=${_timer_list[_i]//[a-z.: ]} && \
     break
done
unset _i _timer_list
readonly TIMER_LIST_OFFSET TIMER_LIST_SKIP

sleepUntilHires() {
    local slp tzoff now quiet=false nsnow nsslp
    [ "$1" = "-q" ] && shift && quiet=true
    local hms=(${1//:/ })
    mapfile -n 1 -s $TIMER_LIST_SKIP nsnow </proc/timer_list
    printf -v now '%(%s)T' -1
    printf -v tzoff '%(%z)T\n' $now
    nsnow=$((${nsnow//[a-z ]}+TIMER_LIST_OFFSET))
    nsslp=$((2000000000-10#${nsnow:${#nsnow}-9}))
    tzoff=$((0${tzoff:0:1}(3600*${tzoff:1:2}+60*${tzoff:3:2})))
    slp=$(( ( 86400 + ( now - now%86400 ) +
            10#$hms*3600+10#${hms[1]}*60+${hms[2]} -
            tzoff - now - 1
        ) % 86400)).${nsslp:1}
    $quiet || printf 'sleep %ss, -> %(%c)T\n' $slp $((now+${slp%.*}+1))
    sleep $slp
}
```

After defining two *read-only* variables, `TIMER_LIST_OFFSET` and `TIMER_LIST_SKIP`, the function will access very quickly the variable file `/proc/timer_list` for computing sleep time:

### Little test function

```bash
tstSleepUntilHires () { 
    local now next last
    printf -v next "%(%H:%M:%S)T" $((${EPOCHREALTIME%.*}+1))
    sleepUntilHires $next
    date -f - +%F-%T.%N < <(echo now;sleep .92;echo now)
    printf -v next "%(%H:%M:%S)T" $((${EPOCHREALTIME%.*}+1))
    sleepUntilHires $next
    date +%F-%T.%N
}
```

May render something like:

```
sleep 0.244040s, -> Wed Apr 22 10:34:39 2020.000000
2020-04-22-10:34:39.001685312
2020-04-22-10:34:39.922291769
sleep 0.077012s, -> Wed Apr 22 10:34:40 2020.000000
2020-04-22-10:34:40.004264869
```

- At begin of next second,
- print time, then
- wait 0.92 seccond, then
- print time, then
- compute 0.07 seconds left, to next second
- sleep 0.07 seconds, then
- print time.

### Jan 2023: New chapter about [GregD's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645992/sleep-until-a-specific-time-date/19067658#comment109639425_645992) and *hibernation*

[GregD's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645992/sleep-until-a-specific-time-date/19067658#comment109639425_645992) warned about *too long sleep* if initiated before computer going into deep sleep mode...

For this I've rewrited `sleepUntilHires`: Of course, they won't wake computer up, but end immediately (max 20 ms) when waked and show time gap.

```bash
sleepUntilHires() { # args: [-q] <HH[:MM[:SS[.xxx]]]> [more days]
    local slp tzoff now quiet=false musec musleep tmu start=${EPOCHREALTIME} tgt
    [[ $_dummySleepFd ]] && [[ -e /dev/fd/$_dummySleepFd ]] ||
        exec {_dummySleepFd}<> <(:)
    [ "$1" = "-q" ] && shift && quiet=true
    local -a hms; IFS=: read -a hms <<<${1}
    printf -v tmu %.06f ${hms[2]:-0}
    printf -v hms[2] %.0f ${tmu%.*}
    tmu=${tmu#*.}; printf -v now '%(%s)T' -1
    IFS=. read now musec <<<$start
    musleep=$((2000000+10#$tmu-10#$musec))
    printf -v tzoff '%(%z)T\n' $now
    tzoff=$((0${tzoff:0:1}(3600*10#${tzoff:1:2}+60*10#${tzoff:3:2})))
    slp=$(((( 86400 + ( now - now%86400 ) +
                10#$hms*3600+10#0${hms[1]:-0}*60+10#${hms[2]:-0} -
                tzoff - now - 1
            ) % 86400 ) + 10#${2:-0} * 86400
          )).${musleep:1}
    tgt=$((${start/.}+10#${slp/.}))
    printf -v tmu  '%(%c)T.%s' $(((${start/.}+10#${slp/.})/1000000)) $tmu
    while ((slp=tgt-${EPOCHREALTIME/.},slp>0)) ;do
        slp=00000$slp
        printf -v slp %.6f ${slp::-6}.${slp: -6}
        $quiet || printf '\rsleep %ss, -> %s ...' "$slp" "$tmu"
        if (( 10#${slp/.} > 20000));then      # If left more than 20 ms
            read -u $_dummySleepFd -t .02 _   # then sleep 20 ms
        else read -u $_dummySleepFd -t $slp _ # else sleep left time
        fi 
    done
    if ! $quiet;then  now=00000$((${EPOCHREALTIME/.}-tgt))
        printf '\nScript done %.6f seconds late.\n' ${now::-6}.${now: -6}
    fi        
}
```

Well I have to start my laptop now...

```
sleepUntilHires 15:13:18.1234
sleep 0.002148s, -> lun 16 jan 2023 15:13:18 CET.123400 ...
Script done 0.000746 seconds late.
```

That was a *normal run*. Now I will put my laptop in hibernation:

```
sleepUntilHires 15:15:18.1234
sleep 86.256328s, -> lun 16 jan 2023 15:15:18 CET.123400 ...
Script done 111.469551 seconds late.
```

Then sleep finish immediately when waked up, and show his final gap.

### Care to not mix `$EPOCHSECOND` and `$EPOCHREALTIME`!

Read my [warning about difference between `$EPOCHSECOND` and `$EPOCHREALTIME`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58557346/1765658)

This function use `$EPOCHREALTIME` so don't use `$EPOCHSECOND` for establishing *next second*:

Sample issue: Trying to print time next rounded by 2 seconds:

```bash
for i in 1 2;do
    printf -v nextEvenSecond "%(%T)T" $(((EPOCHSECONDS/2)*2+2))
    echo $nextEvenSecond
    sleepUntilHires $nextEvenSecond
    IFS=. read now musec <<<$EPOCHREALTIME
    printf "%(%c)T.%s\n" $now $musec
done
```

May produce:

```
11:44:32
sleep 1.485212s, -> Wed Nov  9 11:44:32 2022.000000
Wed Nov  9 11:44:32 2022.000311
11:44:32
sleep 86399.999143s, -> Thu Nov 10 11:44:32 2022.000000
```

You are going to wait 1 day instead of 2 seconds!!!

You have to use `$EPOCHREALTIME`:

```
    printf -v nextEvenSecond "%(%T)T" $(((${EPOCHREALTIME%.*}/2)*2+2))
```

```
11:48:12
sleep 0.300672s, -> Wed Nov  9 11:48:12 2022.000000
Wed Nov  9 11:48:12 2022.000345
11:48:14
sleep 1.998397s, -> Wed Nov  9 11:48:14 2022.000000
Wed Nov  9 11:48:14 2022.000536
11:48:16
sleep 1.998916s, -> Wed Nov  9 11:48:16 2022.000000
Wed Nov  9 11:48:16 2022.000325
```

### About `sleep` and/or `read -t`

In this functions, I use `read -t` (*timeout*) instead of `sleep`, for two reasons:

- this permit user to interrupt *sleep* by hitting <kbd>Return</kbd> key.
  (Variant: `IFS= read -sn 1 -t $slp _`, to permit user to interrupt by hitting <kbd>Any</kbd> key).
- `sleep` implie a call (*fork*) to `/bin/sleep` as it's not a *buitin*.

For avoiding user interrupt by keyboard interaction aka for running this **non interactively**, you could

- create a pseudo *tty* (file descriptor) for redirecting `read`'s input at begin of `sleepUntil.source` script:

```bash
   exec {_dummySleepFd}<> <(:)
```

then replace

```bash
   read -t $slp _
```

by

```bash
   read -u $_dummySleepFd -t $slp _
```

- Load `sleep` *loadable builtin* if your bash implementation permit this (see `sudo apt install bash-builtins`):

```bash
   enable -f sleep sleep
```

if your `$BASH_LOADABLES_PATH` is set, else:

```bash
   enable -f /usr/lib/bash/sleep sleep
```

to unload/disable:

```bash
   enable -d sleep
```

#### some tests (on my raspberry):

```bash
exec {_dummySleepFd}<> <(:)
s=${EPOCHREALTIME/.};read -u $_dummySleepFd -t .01;echo $((${EPOCHREALTIME/.}-s))
10975

s=${EPOCHREALTIME/.};read -u $_dummySleepFd -t .01;echo $((${EPOCHREALTIME/.}-s))
10977
```

With `/bin/sleep`:

```bash
s=${EPOCHREALTIME/.};sleep .01;echo $((${EPOCHREALTIME/.}-s))
60676

s=${EPOCHREALTIME/.};sleep .01;echo $((${EPOCHREALTIME/.}-s))
47910

s=${EPOCHREALTIME/.};sleep .01;echo $((${EPOCHREALTIME/.}-s))
44585
```

First time, `/bin/sleep` was *loaded* from filesystem. this is longer. But anyway, even in *cache*, running a *fork* to `sleep` is ressource killer...

```bash
enable -f /usr/lib/bash/sleep sleep
s=${EPOCHREALTIME/.};sleep .01;echo $((${EPOCHREALTIME/.}-s))
10803

s=${EPOCHREALTIME/.};sleep .01;echo $((${EPOCHREALTIME/.}-s))
10760
```

Seem a little better than using `read -u $_dummySleepFd -t ...`

Comment: Wow! Computing **nanoseconds** under [tag:bash]!

Comment: Computing micro seconds under native bash v5+!!

Comment: Pedantic note: the `%86400` trick only works if the two times do not span a daylight saving time transition.

Comment: @200_success You may apply time offset: Search for `tzoff` in my answer!

Comment: I'm now newly getting `bash: 0-(3600*08: value too great for base (error token is "08")` with the `sleepUntil` function.

Comment: @hlidka: Thanks, correct bug about *`TZ`* : Tested by `LANG=C TZ=UTC+9 sleepUntil 09:09:09 09` and `LANG=C TZ=UTC+9 sleepUntilHires 09:09:09.009 09
`

Comment: The **Simple starting sample** is perfect for some commands that I need to run when the second hand hits 0, 15, 30 and 45.

Comment: Note that the printf `%T` directive does not exist/work in `/bin/bash` on macOS.

Comment: @RonJohn I've added a chapter regarding your comment for *`sleepUntilNext <period>`*!

Comment: I want to note that `{ read -u $no_fd -t $timeout; do_smth; } &` process can be suspended and resumed with `-STOP` and `-CONT` signals **with the timer also suspended** unlike `sleep` which immediately returns on wakeup if sleep time has passed. This is what I was looking for, Thanks!

Comment: i added that function to my .zshrc, but when running the sample command i get:
`sleepUntil 10:37 ; date +"Now, it is: %T"
sleepUntil:printf:4: %(: invalid directive
sleepUntil:printf:5: %(: invalid directive`

i'm on MacOS Sonoma.

Comment: @ezekiel87 [tag:zsh] is not [tag:bash]! This function use so called *bashisms*! You could try to install [tag:bash] under MacOS with [tag:brew].... Or try Linux! 

Answer (score 25):

Use `sleep`, but compute the time using `date`. You'll want to use `date -d` for this. For example, let's say you wanted to wait until next week:

```
expr `date -d "next week" +%s` - `date -d "now" +%s`
```

Just substitute "next week" with whatever date you'd like to wait for, then assign this expression to a value, and sleep for that many seconds:

```
startTime=$(date +%s)
endTime=$(date -d "next week" +%s)
timeToWait=$(($endTime- $startTime))
sleep $timeToWait
```

All done!

Comment: It's worth expanding on how you'd assign the value to a variable, since timeToWait=expr ... won't work directly, and you can't use backticks because they won't nest, so you'll have to use $(), or temporary variables.

Comment: Good suggestion; I'll modify mine to make that clearer so that people don't get the wrong idea.

Comment: Note `-d` is a non-POSIX extension to date. On FreeBSD it tries to set the kernel's value for daylight saving time.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a simple Bash one-liner:

```
sleep $(expr $(date -d "03/21/2014 12:30" +%s) - $(date +%s))
```

Comment: This is precisely the solution I was looking for. Very concise.

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I get an error `sleep: invalid option -- '2'`

Comment: @Jan yes it still does, I've just tested. This message is displayed when the date you give as string after `-d` argument is in the past compared to your current system date. In order to show what is the current date of your system, just type in `date` in your console.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a solution that does the job AND informs the user about how much time is remaining.
I use it almost everyday to run scripts during the night (using cygwin, as I couldn't get `cron` to work on windows)

## Features

- Precise down to the second
- Detects system time changes and adapts
- Intelligent output telling how much time is left
- 24-hour input format
- returns true to be able to chain with `&&`

## Sample run

```
$ til 13:00 && date
1 hour and 18 minutes and 26 seconds left...
1 hour and 18 minutes left...
1 hour and 17 minutes left...
1 hour and 16 minutes left...
1 hour and 15 minutes left...
1 hour and 14 minutes left...
1 hour and 10 minutes left...
1 hour and  5 minutes left...
1 hour and  0 minutes left...
55 minutes left...
50 minutes left...
45 minutes left...
40 minutes left...
35 minutes left...
30 minutes left...
25 minutes left...
20 minutes left...
15 minutes left...
10 minutes left...
 5 minutes left...
 4 minutes left...
 3 minutes left...
 2 minutes left...
 1 minute left...
Mon, May 18, 2015  1:00:00 PM
```

(The date at the end is not part of the function, but due to the `&& date`)

## Code

```
til(){
  local hour mins target now left initial sleft correction m sec h hm hs ms ss showSeconds toSleep
  showSeconds=true
  [[ $1 =~ ([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9]) ]] || { echo >&2 "USAGE: til HH:MM"; return 1; }
  hour=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} mins=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  target=$(date +%s -d "$hour:$mins") || return 1
  now=$(date +%s)
  (( target > now )) || target=$(date +%s -d "tomorrow $hour:$mins")
  left=$((target - now))
  initial=$left
  while (( left > 0 )); do
    if (( initial - left < 300 )) || (( left < 300 )) || [[ ${left: -2} == 00 ]]; then
      # We enter this condition:
      # - once every 5 minutes
      # - every minute for 5 minutes after the start
      # - every minute for 5 minutes before the end
      # Here, we will print how much time is left, and re-synchronize the clock

      hs= ms= ss=
      m=$((left/60)) sec=$((left%60)) # minutes and seconds left
      h=$((m/60)) hm=$((m%60)) # hours and minutes left

      # Re-synchronise
      now=$(date +%s) sleft=$((target - now)) # recalculate time left, multiple 60s sleeps and date calls have some overhead.
      correction=$((sleft-left))
      if (( ${correction#-} > 59 )); then
        echo "System time change detected..."
        (( sleft <= 0 )) && return # terminating as the desired time passed already
        til "$1" && return # resuming the timer anew with the new time
      fi

      # plural calculations
      (( sec > 1 )) && ss=s
      (( hm != 1 )) && ms=s
      (( h > 1 )) && hs=s

      (( h > 0 )) && printf %s "$h hour$hs and "
      (( h > 0 || hm > 0 )) && printf '%2d %s' "$hm" "minute$ms"
      if [[ $showSeconds ]]; then
        showSeconds=
        (( h > 0 || hm > 0 )) && (( sec > 0 )) && printf %s " and "
        (( sec > 0 )) && printf %s "$sec second$ss"
        echo " left..."
        (( sec > 0 )) && sleep "$sec" && left=$((left-sec)) && continue
      else
        echo " left..."
      fi
    fi
    left=$((left-60))
    sleep "$((60+correction))"
    correction=0
  done
}
```

Comment: Trying on MacOS Sonoma.
Added the func to my .zshrc
Now when running the sample command i get:
`til 13:00 && date
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-I[date|hours|minutes|seconds]] [-f input_fmt]
            [-r filename|seconds] [-v[+|-]val[y|m|w|d|H|M|S]]
            [[[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.SS] | new_date] [+output_fmt]`

Comment: Zsh is another language. There are so many changes needed for it to work on zsh...

Answer (score 9):

You can stop a process from executing, by sending it a SIGSTOP signal, and then get it to resume executing by sending it a SIGCONT signal.

So you could stop your script by sending is a SIGSTOP:

```
kill -SIGSTOP <pid>
```

And then use the at deamon to wake it up by sending it a SIGCONT in the same way.

Presumably, your script will inform at of when it wanted to be woken up before putting itself to sleep.

Answer (score 9):

I wanted an script that only checked the hours and minutes so I could run the script with the same parameters every day. I don't want to worry about which day will be tomorrow. So I used a different approach.

```
target="$1.$2"
cur=$(date '+%H.%M')
while test $target != $cur; do
    sleep 59
    cur=$(date '+%H.%M')
done
```

the parameters to the script are the hours and minutes, so I can write something like:

```
til 7 45 && mplayer song.ogg
```

(til is the name of the script)

no more days late at work cause you mistyped the day. cheers!

Comment: A very minor detail if precision is important: 
if just before deadline (<1 minute) it always waits at least 59 seconds. Furthermore this script 59 out of 60 times on average won't run exactly on time.

Comment: Btw you can easily wrap the code in a function (no code changes needed) and call it inside a shell script like this `till 7 45`

Comment: For those on MacOS, try specifying the hour in double digit: `til 07 45`

Also, if you want to run directly as cmd, add this code to your shell rc (mine is .zshrc)
`til(){
 target="$1.$2"
 cur=$(date '+%H.%M')
 while test $target != $cur; do
     sleep 30
     cur=$(date '+%H.%M')
     echo waiting until $target
 done
}`

Answer (score 7):

To follow on SpoonMeiser's answer, here's a specific example:

```
$cat ./reviveself

#!/bin/bash

# save my process ID
rspid=$$

# schedule my own resuscitation
# /bin/sh seems to dislike the SIGCONT form, so I use CONT
# at can accept specific dates and times as well as relative ones
# you can even do something like "at thursday" which would occur on a 
# multiple of 24 hours rather than the beginning of the day
echo "kill -CONT $rspid"|at now + 2 minutes

# knock myself unconscious
# bash is happy with symbolic signals
kill -SIGSTOP $rspid

# do something to prove I'm alive
date>>reviveself.out
$
```

Comment: I think you want to schedule a SIGCONT, rather than another SIGSTOP, so either the signal, or the comment is wrong. Otherwise, nice to see a proper example.

Comment: Oops, I typo'd the comment. Now fixed. But you have to watch using numeric signals, since they can be different.

Comment: I found that dash seems to not understand SIGCONT, so at first I used -18 which is non-portable, then I found that it likes CONT, so I edited the answer above to fix that.

Answer (score 4):

> timeToWait = $(( $end - $start ))

Beware that "timeToWait" could be a negative number! (for example, if you specify to sleep until "15:57" and now it's "15:58"). So you have to check it to avoid strange message errors:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o nounset

### // Sleep until some date/time. 
# // Example: sleepuntil 15:57; kdialog --msgbox "Backup needs to be done."


error() {
  echo "$@" >&2
  exit 1;
}

NAME_PROGRAM=$(basename "$0")

if [[ $# != 1 ]]; then
     error "ERROR: program \"$NAME_PROGRAM\" needs 1 parameter and it has received: $#." 
fi


current=$(date +%s.%N)
target=$(date -d "$1" +%s.%N)

seconds=$(echo "scale=9; $target - $current" | bc)

signchar=${seconds:0:1}
if [ "$signchar" = "-" ]; then
     error "You need to specify in a different way the moment in which this program has to finish, probably indicating the day and the hour like in this example: $NAME_PROGRAM \"2009/12/30 10:57\"."
fi

sleep "$seconds"

# // End of file
```

Comment: Good solution, however, I think $SECONDS is a string so the defensive code should be something like get a substring first like so `SIGNCHAR=${SECONDS:0:1}` and then
`if [ "$SIGNCHAR" = "-" ]`.  That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

I actually wrote https://tamentis.com/projects/sleepuntil/ for this exact purpose.  It's a bit over-kill most of the code comes from BSD 'at' so it's fairly standard-compliant:

```
$ sleepuntil noon && sendmail something
```

Comment: Care about [differences between c time() and gettimeofday()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31315064/1765658)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the number of seconds between now and the wake-up time and use the existing 'sleep' command.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use 'at' to send a signal to your script, which sat waiting for that signal.

Comment: Aww man, I was just writing up another answer to this effect.

Comment: Well, actually, no, mine was slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

To extend the main answer, here is some valid examples regarding the date string manipulation:

```
sleep $(($(date -f - +%s- <<< $'+3 seconds\nnow')0)) && ls

sleep $(($(date -f - +%s- <<< $'3 seconds\nnow')0)) && ls

sleep $(($(date -f - +%s- <<< $'3 second\nnow')0)) && ls

sleep $(($(date -f - +%s- <<< $'+2 minute\nnow')0)) && ls

sleep $(($(date -f - +%s- <<< $'tomorrow\nnow')0)) && ls

sleep $(($(date -f - +%s- <<< $'tomorrow 21:30\nnow')0)) && ls

sleep $(($(date -f - +%s- <<< $'3 weeks\nnow')0)) && ls

sleep $(($(date -f - +%s- <<< $'3 week\nnow')0)) && ls

sleep $(($(date -f - +%s- <<< $'next Friday 09:00\nnow')0)) && ls

sleep $(($(date -f - +%s- <<< $'2027-01-01 00:00:01 UTC +5 hours\nnow')0)) && ls
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice little Rust CLI tool [yawn](https://github.com/cfal/yawn/) that does the job. If you have Rust installed already then this might be an easy option (`cargo install yawn`). Otherwise, Apple and Linux executables are available on Github.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I wrote just now to synchronise multiple test clients:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import sys

now = time.time()
mod = float(sys.argv[1])
until = now - now % mod + mod
print "sleeping until", until

while True:
    delta = until - time.time()
    if delta <= 0:
        print "done sleeping ", time.time()
        break
    time.sleep(delta / 2)
```

This script sleeps until next "rounded" or "sharp" time.

A simple use case is to run `./sleep.py 10; ./test_client1.py` in one terminal and `./sleep.py 10; ./test_client2.py` in another.

Comment: Where is the connection to my question?

Comment: it's easy to extend so that `until` is set to a specific date/time

Answer (score 0):

```
 function sleepuntil() {
  local target_time="$1"
  today=$(date +"%m/%d/%Y")
  current_epoch=$(date +%s)
  target_epoch=$(date -d "$today $target_time" +%s)
  sleep_seconds=$(( $target_epoch - $current_epoch ))

  sleep $sleep_seconds
}

target_time="11:59"; sleepuntil $target_time
```

Comment: Can you add some sort of description to this solution?

Comment: this is a bash script; function sleepuntil takes one argument; you set the variable target_time="11:59" or whatever time you want to sleep until; then you call the function with the target_time argument. It calculates how many seconds are till that target time and sleeps for that amount of seconds

Answer (score 0):

I put together a small utility called [Hypnos](https://github.com/transitorykris/hypnos) to do this. It's configured using the crontab syntax and blocks until that time.

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]; do
  hypnos "0 * * * *"
  echo "running some tasks..."
  # ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider also this concise Bash one-liner:

```
sleep $((`date -d "22:00" +%s`-`date  +%s`))
```

This is a Bash v4.4.20(1) arithmetic expression, consisting of two date command substitutions. The first date command outputs your target until time in seconds (since 1970) and the latter the respective current time. These two numbers are separated by a minus sign for the arithmetic. As a result, you get seconds as a parameter for the sleep command.

Answer (score 0):

This script will wait until *4 of July, 21:44:59*

```
while (( $(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S") < 20220704214459 )); do :; done
echo "It is time!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here comes a final countdown solution using standard `pv` tool that comes with your distro.

- Use any `date` compatible expression instead of `5 min`.
- Play with `pv` parameters to get output as you want.

```
SECS=$(( $(date -d '5 min' +%s)-$(date +%s) )) && pv -L1 -s$SECS -petlI <(seq $SECS) >/dev/null
```

Answer (score -1):

On **OpenBSD**, the following could be used to compact a `*/5` 5-minute [`crontab(5)`](http://mdoc.su/o/crontab.5) job into an `00` hourly one (to make sure fewer emails are generated, all whilst performing the same task at exact intervals):

```
#!/bin/sh -x
for k in $(jot 12 00 55)
  do
  echo $(date) doing stuff
  sleep $(expr $(date -j +%s $(printf %02d $(expr $k + 5))) - $(date -j +%s))
done
```

Note that the [`date(1)`](http://mdoc.su/o/date.1) would also break the [`sleep(1)`](http://mdoc.su/o/sleep.1) by design on the final iteration, as `60` minutes is not a valid time (unless it is!), thus we won't have to wait any extra time prior to getting our email report.

Also note that should one of the iterations take more than 5 minutes allotted to it, the `sleep` would likewise graciously fail by design by not sleeping at all (due to what is a negative number interpreted as a command-line option, instead of wrapping around to the next hour or even eternity), thus making sure your job could still complete within the hour allotted (e.g., if only one of the iterations takes a little bit more than 5 minutes, then we would still have the time to catch up, without anything wrapping around to the next hour).

The [`printf(1)`](http://mdoc.su/o/printf.1) is needed because `date` expects exactly two digits for the minute specification.

Answer (score -1):

Use tarry.  It's a tool I wrote to specifically do this.

https://github.com/metaphyze/tarry/

This is a simple command line tool for waiting until a specific time. This is not the same as "sleep" which will wait for a duration of time. This is useful if you want to execute something at a specific time or more likely execute several things at exactly the same time such as testing if a server can handle multiple very simultaneous requests. You could use it like this with "&&" on Linux, Mac, or Windows:

```
   tarry -until=16:03:04 && someOtherCommand
```

This would wait until 4:03:04 PM and then execute someOtherCommand. Here's a Linux/Mac example of how to run multiple requests all scheduled to start at the same time:

```
   for request in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
   do
       tarry -until=16:03:04 && date > results.$request &
   done
```

Ubuntu, Linux, and Windows binaries are available through links on the page.