# at command is not executed

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to make the `at` bash command to run, but it is not working for me. I can add a job to the queue, but it is not run when the time is up. What am I doing wrong?

```
hpek@melda:~$ cat /usr/lib/cron/at.deny 
hpek@melda:~$ atq
hpek@melda:~$ at now +2 minutes
echo TTTEEEST
job 12 at Sun May  6 02:09:00 2012
hpek@melda:~$ date
Sun May  6 02:10:24 CEST 2012
hpek@melda:~$ atq
12  Sun May  6 02:09:00 2012
hpek@melda:~$
```

UPD2021.08.06 atd was removed in MacOS 11.5.2 (or earlier)

```
$ sudo find / -name atd -print 2>/dev/null
$
```

Comment: Are you running a [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) tool such as [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/)? Any of these could restrict `cron(8)` from running jobs or saving output.

Comment: I have not mentioned that I am on a mac - because I did not think that it was important. I now believe that the answer can be found here: http://superuser.com/questions/43678/mac-os-x-at-command-not-working . I will soon delete this question, because it is a duplicate.

Comment: Ha! Thanks for the feedback; I wish there were an easy way to close-as-duplicate of content on another site, because the phrasing of this question is good and may help someone else find the problem in the future.

Comment: at daemon is running?

Comment: @Leonardo Hermoso: Please read answers.

Comment: Maybe cout this: [sleep util specific time/date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19067658/1765658) answer your need!

Comment: Duplicates
https://superuser.com/questions/43678/mac-os-x-at-command-not-working
that has answers that are still applicable to macosx 11

Comment: A duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/43678/mac-os-x-at-command-not-working muru's answer with launchctl to the rescue

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478823/making-at-work-on-macos/478840#478840 worked for me on macOS 11.2.1

Comment: thanks. it was working without full disk access though. don't remember what I did but It runs now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at `/var/at/jobs` and see if your at jobs are listed there. (It may be a different directory based upon OS).

By default, `at` isn't enabled on most systems. In order for `at` jobs to actually get executed, the [atrun](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/atrun/) command must execute.

This command is executed either through [launchd](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/launchd.plist/) or through the [cron](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/cron/) depending upon the system.

The exact mechanisms are different from system to system, so you'll have to read all the various manpages on `at`, `atrun`, etc. to verify if `at` is really enabled on your system, and whether you have permissions to run at jobs. There's normally both an *ant allow* and an *ant deny* file on your system, so you need to check both. You must be both in the *allowed* file, and also not in the *deny* file.

On top of that, you have to make sure that `at` is even enabled on your system (due to security concerns, it is usually disabled).

Comment: Do you know where is the location of /var/at/jobs in cent OS 7?

Comment: /var/spool/cron/atjobs for Ubuntu

Answer (score 7):

It is working fine. It's just that commands running with `at` don't write their output to the terminal that you called it from.

Try:

```
at now +2 minutes
echo TTTEEEST > new_file_test
```

You'll see the file appear in two minutes.

Comment: How about if you give an absolute pathname? Probably `at(1)` is executing the script either in your home directory or its home directory. (Mine executes in my user's home directory; tested with `/bin/pwd > /tmp/pwd`.)

Comment: @sarnold: No - it is not working. Is your job removed(from `atq`) when the time is up?

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen Yup, you're right. Sorry for the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check your mail:

```
   An at - or batch - command invoked from a su(1) shell will
   retain the current userid.  The user will be mailed standard
   error and standard output from his commands, if any.  Mail
   will be sent using the command /usr/sbin/sendmail.  If at is
   executed from a su(1) shell, the owner of the login shell
   will receive the mail.
```

Comment: I have not recieved any new mail.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this [here](https://www.simplehelp.net/2009/05/04/how-to-schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-the-at-command/)

> First make sure that the at daemon is running using a command like this:
>
> ```
> # ps -ef | grep atd
> root 8231 1 0 18:10 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/atd
> ```
>
> If you don’t see atd running start it with this command:
>
> ```
> # /etc/init.d/atd start
> ```

Comment: $ /etc/init.d/atd start
-bash: /etc/init.d/atd: No such file or directory someone made an "improvement" in 11.5.2

Comment: whoa! $ ls -la /etc/init.d
ls: /etc/init.d: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Conclution First:
`atrun` or `atd` daemon is not running, causing this problem.

Guideline to solve your case:

1. check `at` mannul by `man at` first.
   In my case, I(macos 10.13.6) found following info:

> ```
>  Note that at is implemented through the launchd(8) daemon periodically invoking atrun(8), which is disabled by default.  See atrun(8) for information about enabling atrun.
> ```

2. check `atrun` mannul by `man atrun`, I found :

> The atrun utility runs commands queued by at(1).  It is invoked periodically by launchd(8) as specified in the com.apple.atrun.plist property list.  By default the property list contains the
> Disabled key set to true, so atrun is never invoked.

3. Execute the following command as **root** to enable atrun:
   `launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist`

Answer (score 0):

To analyze at(d) execution problems it may help to

1. Check /etc/at.allow and /etc/at.deny for existance and contents (see `man at.allow`)
2. Check owner and access rights of the atd spool directory
   (/var/spool/cron/atjobs, daemon:daemon, 770 on Ubuntu)
3. Check if atd daemon is running (`systemctrl -a | grep atd` on Ubuntu)
4. `tail -f /var/log/syslog` (at execution time)
5. `journalctl -b | grep atd` (found that [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/at-command-permission-denied/55852/6), contains further hints)

The "Permission denied" error may also be caused by limited number of logins defined (for the `at` running user) in /etc/security/limits.conf.

Comment: antonsmbp:tango atropashko$ journalctl -b | grep atd
-bash: journalctl: command not found
antonsmbp:tango atropashko$ sudo journalctl -b | grep atd
sudo: journalctl: command not found

Comment: @AntonTropashko which OS are you trying on?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same issue with echo when used along with `at` command. But if you try to redirect the output using `>` or `>>` then it works perfectly. Also try some other system commands like `reboot`, `ls > some_text_file` etc to make sure at command is working. Else try
`sudo systemctl enable --now atd` to enable `at` daemon

Comment: sudo systemctl enable --now atd