# How to run "at" command every hour

Tags: shell, sh

how can I programm with the "at" command  that below runs at 6:00,7.00,8:00,9:00,10:00 until 23.00

```
cmd = "echo /bin/everyhour | at 06:00"
```

regards
gwaag

Comment: Why you add python tag?

Comment: @kamesh haha it might be a better option but I'm actual curious as to what the exact answer is to this question is! (I was actually wondering how the bash "at" works last night!)

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yea seems like it wants the "bash" tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a bash command run periodically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394356/how-can-i-make-a-bash-command-run-periodically)

Comment: Doesn't matter - it's asked in a different (and I'd think much more searchable) way so people may be (as I was) more likely to come across it.

Comment: at is for single executions of a command at a given time. If you want to periodically run something (e.g. "every hour"), use cron.

Answer (score 3):

The **at** command is used to schedule commands to be executed once. For recurring executions I would suggest **cron**.
Edit your crontab with `crontab -e` and add the follow line:

```
00 06-23 * * * /bin/everyhour
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting this in your `.bashrc`, not tested though:

```
doer() {
  t=$(date +"%k")
  bin/everyhour
  if [[ $t < 24 && $t > 5 ]]; then
      echo doer | at now + 1 hour
  fi  
}
doer
```

or, this one keeps on working but only executes on specified interval:

```
doer() {
  t=$(date +"%k")
  if [[ $t < 24 && $t > 5 ]]; then
      bin/everyhour
  fi  
  echo doer | at now + 1 hour
}
```

Comment: You might want to test this.  I don't think aliases are passed through to at.

Comment: @JohnC: It's a function, not an alias. But you're right that `at` won't be able to see it. More to the point, the solution to this problem is `cron`, not `at`

Comment: @JohnC, yes it is a function but same can be achieved via a script in `bin` for example. And surely `cron` is the right tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script which will call `at` command and later the right job. Following one will run a job every hour but with small modification you can also reach hours between 6:00 - 23:00:

```
at now + 1 hour -m -f ~/scheduledTask.sh

#do the job
~/job.sh
```

Then you are running this script at a given time using `at` command:

```
at 06:00 -m -f ~/scheduledTask.sh
```