# Delay in running a command in a shell script

Tags: shell, unix, command, timedelay

I have written a shell script which includes some commands to collect various Test logs.But I want to put waiting time before a particular command so that it will run after 30 mins after starting the shell script.Anyone having the knowledge regarding it please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `at` command to schedule a job to run at any time:

```
echo "/my_path/my_script" | at now + 30 minutes
```

If you want a delay inside your script you can sleep to a specific time using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/646008/2413778) solution.