# Shell infinite loop to execute at specific time

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have access to a Linux CentOS box.  (I can't use crontab sadly)

When I need to run a task everyday I have just created a infinite loop with a sleep.  (it runs, sleeps ~24 hours and then runs again)

```
#!/bin/sh


while :
do
    /home/sas_api_emailer.sh |& tee first_sas_api

sleep 1438m
done
```

Recently I have a task that I need to run at a specific time everyday 6:00 am (I can't use crontab)

How can I create an infinite loop that will only execute @ 6:00 am?

Comment: @muru All the answers there use `crontab` or `at`.

Comment: You said you can't use `crontab`. Why not `at`?

Comment: Why can't you use the tools designed to handle the job you are seeking to handle?  That is, why can't you use `cron`?  Are you sure that decision is unchangeable?  Why don't you get your own `cron` program installed and use that instead of the system version?

Comment: `crontab` is per user, so you should be able to add tasks to your user's crontab without effecting other users (or needing special permission, unless the box is very, very locked down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the time in the loop, and then sleep for a minute if it's not the time you want.

```
while :
do
    if [ $(date '+%H%M') = '0600' ]
    then /home/sas_api_emailer.sh |& tee first_sas_api
    fi
    sleep 60
done
```

Comment: Why is that? if you start it at `5:45`, it will sleep for a minute, run again at `5:46`, sleep again, and so on until it gets to `06:00`. Then it will execute the command and return to the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the additional context

Answer (score 1):

You have (at least!) three choices:

1. [cron](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=78)

   This is hands-down the best choice.  Unfortunately, you say it's not an option for you.  Drag :(
2. [at](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at)

   > at and batch read commands from standard input or a specified file
   >   which are to be executed at a later time.

   For example: `at -f myjob noon`

   Here is more information about `at`:  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/at-atq-atrm-batch-command-examples/
3. Write a "polling" or "while loop" script.  For example:

   ```
   while true
     # Compute wait time
     sleep wait_time
     # do something
   done
   ```

   Here are some good ideas for "compute wait time": [Bash: Sleep until a specific time/date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645992/bash-sleep-until-a-specific-time-date)