# Schedule Python Script in Bash?

Tags: python, bash, automation, scheduling

I am new to scheduling python scripts and need to start a script so it can run for a day or two.  I am not allowed to use cron in my environment so am using this bash script.  What is a simple test I can do to make sure the python file runs?  How would I know that my file ran?  And also, if it throws an error, how can I make sure I am notified?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while true
do
    DATE="$(date +'%d')"
    MONTH="$(date +'%m')"
    YEAR="$(date +'%Y')"
    HOUR="$(date +'%H')"
    MINUTE="$(date +'%M')"
    if ([ "$DATE" = "27" ]) && [ "$HOUR" = "12" ] && [ "$MINUTE" = "30" ]
    then
                 /my_file.py
        sleep 24h
    fi
done
```

Comment: So, you are trying to reimplement the features of cron, because you have a weird reason not to use it?

Comment: What do you think night happen on that line *instead* of running your script?  Are you just asking how to check or react to an exit status?

Comment: Consider adding a small sleep (e.g., 30 seconds) into the loop.  Otherwise, the script will consume lot of CPU. Also are you sure that the path to your job in '/my_file.py' (in the root folder ?).

Comment: Also look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645992/bash-sleep-until-a-specific-time-date

Answer (score 1):

I've added a small snippet.

With the variable `TRIGGER` you can select your date when the script (`cron.sh` or in your case course `cron.py`) should be started the first time.

`WAIT` determines the span between on run of the script (`cron`) and the next run (e. g. *5 minutes* or *24 hours*) In my example I'm just waiting 5 minutes till the next run.

Then we are checking if the Process ID of the started script `cron.sh` exists und react to this:

- PID not available and return value not zero: We need to restart the script.
  There has been an error.
- PID not available and return value zero: Increment the trigger (waiting time).
  No error.

**Note that this is just an approach and very quick and dirty.** 
This should only demonstrate how this can be done. You can take this and implement your own functionality now (notifications, logging, etc.)

Additionally:

- You can check, how often the cron-script has been started. For example set a limit for restarting the cron. If the cron-script fails multiple times in a row, you should deactive this and notify the User.
- If you want to be notified in case your script has failed multiple times, I personally like the option to send a mail: [Send Mail via Terminal](https://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/)
- Working with arrays and loops, it's possible to monitor more than one Python- or bash-script.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Select how long between each run should be waited
WAIT="5 minutes"


process_started=false
tmp_pid=0

# For starting a detached process
startProcess() { 
    ./cron.sh &>/dev/null &
    tmp_pid=$(echo $!)
    process_started=true;
    return 0
}


# Make the current date to the staring point
TRIGGER=$(date +'%d-%m-%y-%H-%M') 
echo "Starting Point: $TRIGGER"

while true
do
  # Check for the trigger
  if [ $(date +'%d-%m-%y-%H-%M') = "$TRIGGER" ]; then
    # No process has been stared. Start the proces now
    if [ "$process_started" = false ]; then
      startProcess
      echo "Started script: "  $(date +'%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S') " (PID $tmp_pid)"
    fi

    # Check for existence
    if ! kill -0 $tmp_pid > /dev/null 2>&1; then
      echo "No process found with pid $tmp_pid" >&2
      # Now, no process has been found. 
      # We can check of the exit code to determine
      # if the process has exited normally
      wait ${tmp_pid}
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
       echo "Script exited normal: " $(date +'%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')" . Waiting another $WAIT"
        # Process has been exited normally.
        # Resetting the trigger.
        TRIGGER=$(date +'%d-%m-%y-%H-%M' -d "$WAIT")
        echo "New run in $WAIT: $TRIGGER"
      else
        echo "Script exited with an error"
        # Here. e. g. Start the script again
        startProcess
        echo "Retarted script: "  $(date +'%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S') " (PID $tmp_pid)"
      fi
    fi
    sleep 1s
  fi
done
```

This of course also works with a python script. Just change the function `startProcess`:

```sh
startProcess() { 
    ./cron.py &>/dev/null &
    tmp_pid=$(echo $!)
    process_started=true;
    return 0
}
```

and don't forget to include `#!/usr/bin/env python3` in your `cron.py` file.

---

With the following `cron.sh`

```
x=1
while [ $x -le 5 ]
do
  x=$(( $x + 1 ))
  sleep 1s
done
exit 0
```

you will receive the output:

```
Starting Point: 20-10-19-05-22
Started script:  20-10-19 05:22:36  (PID 86402)
No process found with pid 86402
Script exited normal:  20-10-19 05:22:46. Waiting another 5 minutes
New run in 5 minutes: 20-10-19-05-27
```