# How do I parse and move a csv file once a file has been moved into a specific location?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I’m very new to python and data science in general, however, I would love feedback on how to accomplish this and any recommendations. I have written a Python script with the help of pandas to reformat a .csv file into the correct format for import onto an instrument (BioRad CFX384 for you biologists). I would like to make this script work for a broad range of .csv files instead of just one at a time.

The goal would be to save a non-import-formatted file into a folder then have this script reformat the newly added csv files every 3-5 minutes. After writing to the file, it will move the newly formatted file into a nested folder. How do I complete this part?

I have all the formatting done—-all I need to do is generalize the script to work for all the csvs in a folder and move them into the new location. I imagine I will probably utilize `import os`.

Here is the code I have so far

```
import pandas as pd
mydata = pd.read_csv("Example_Export_File_2.csv", header = 6)

mydata.drop(["Position", "ID_1", "Name"], axis = 1, inplace = True)

mydata["*Target Name"]= "N1"

mydata["*Biological Group"]= "Respiratory"

mydata.columns = ['*Sample Name', '*Target Name', '*Biological Group']

new_column = pd.DataFrame({'Row': [
    'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 
    'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',
    'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C',
    'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D',
    'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E',
    'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F',
    'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G',
    'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H',
    'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I',
    'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J',
    'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K',
    'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L',
    'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M',
    'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N',
    'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O',
    'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P',]})
mydata = mydata.merge(new_column, left_index = True, right_index = True)

new_column = pd.DataFrame({'Column': [
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', 
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',]})
mydata = mydata.merge(new_column, left_index = True, right_index = True)
mydata = mydata[['Row', 'Column', '*Target Name', '*Sample Name', '*Biological Group']]

mydata.to_csv("Example_Export_File_2.csv", index=False)

print(mydata)
```

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: depends on what all the other csvs look like. sounds like you need a way of finding the right index in place of the hardcoded column/header index.

Comment: All of the csv files will look exactly the same, the only thing that will differ is their file name and their contents in two of the columns. Here is a link so you can see the files that will be located in the folder in which the script will act on. https://gofile.io/d/vkrGSi

Comment: okay, so your question is how do you do this same transformation across a bunch of files in a directory? edit: I see now, a new file shows up every few minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to address your question -- I'll say outright that there are ways to schedule a script to run but they vary in how easy they are to implement and how reliable they are. I'll find a link that goes into detail ([scheduling python script with bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58469601/schedule-python-script-in-bash)).

For my response, I'll just say that doing this type of thing in batches, manually, is much easier.

If your python script is in the same directory then `os.listdir()` will give you a list of all the files. I usually throw some kind of list comprehension on top of that to grab only csvs

```
[i for i in filelist if '.csv' in i]
```

With a list of the files in your local directory, it's a matter of doing a for loop over your `pd.read_csv` *process some stuff* then `df.to_csv`

Navigating a directory is a little more complicated but you use the same `os` package. [SO post for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Comment: Thank you @will.cass.wrig ! I seem to be importing the directory list properly but when I compile that script with my reformatting script, it says `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File Example_Export_File.csv does not exist: 'Example_Export_File.csv'` Any ideas as to why I am getting this error? It's clearly reading the directory properly and I know the file is in the directory.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I used a different method. I used `for file in glob.glob("/my directory/*.csv"):
    pd.read_csv(open(file, 'rb'), header = 1)
    mydata =pd.read_csv(open(file, 'r'), header = 6)`

Comment: I've never used `open` within `read_csv` since it has a built-in open function ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)). Glad you got things working! I don't miss my days in the lab but I sympathize.